# falcon cors not returning correct headers

Tags: python, cors, falconframework

In my configuration I have:

```
cors = CORS(allow_all_origins=True,
            allow_headers_list=['authorization','content-type'],
            allow_all_methods=True)

app = falcon.API(middleware=[
    cors.middleware,
    PeeweeConnectionMiddleware(),
    MultipartMiddleware(),
    auth_middleware,
])
```

but when I try to make a request using axios, firefox tries the preflight request and it blocks the actual request with the following error:

```
Reason: missing token ‘authorization’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’
```

I have tried also using `allow_all_headers=True`but the request always fails. What could be the problem?

In the console I can read:

```
Aborting response due to unallowed method
[pid: 26577|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {42 vars in 697 bytes} [Sun May 20 16:54:29 2018] OPTIONS /api/v1/auth => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 164 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: try to put `allow_all_headers=True` in CORS

Comment: @zimdero As I mentioned in the post I've already tried it without positive results

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation for why using *allow_all_headers* is not working for you, but the configuration that works for me is the following:

```
cors = CORS(allow_origins_list=['*'],
            allow_all_origins=True,
            allow_all_headers=True,
            allow_all_methods=True)
```